# use rsa_id file with git

Tags: git, ssh

I have a git bash installed and the following file : "myname.rsa_id"

I also have a git repository link : ssh://apache@xxxx:/appli/apache/git/folders.git

When I am doing git clone link, it's asking me a password which I don't have, I know that I have to use the rsa file, but I don't know how, I have already tried multiple methods, like adding the file in a .ssh folder in the home git, but it's not working.

Does anyone could explain me how to clone the repository.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Git will look for a private key named **id_rsa**. The other alternative is to add the key to your SSH agent so that it will be used automatically when connecting via SSH.

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/myname.rsa_id
```

You'll need to make sure your SSH agent is running for this to work. What operating system are you running?

Comment: I am running on windows. So you are telling me to put my file in a .ssh folder (which i have to create), then run git bash, write your command (ssh-add) and then git clone ?

Comment: When I run git bash and then write ssh-add, I am getting the following message : "could not open a connection to your authentification agent".

Comment: It's been a while since I've done it in windows, but i'm fairly certain that if you drop it in this folder `c:\users\your-username\.ssh` and rename to **id_rsa** (no file extension), it should just work.